# (Dijkstra's) How to efficiently find a HashMap key with minimum value that's also in another set?

Tags: java, sorting, graph-theory, dijkstra

I'm implementing Dijkstra's Algorithm following [this pseudocode from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Pseudocode), and I'm a bit stuck on speeding up the algorithm. I know I can use a Priority Queue/Fib Heap too for optimality, but I don't quite understand those 2 yet, and I'd like to get started with the basic implementation first.

One of the parts is finding the vertex with the minimum value in `dist` that's also in a set `Q` (by the pseudocode).

(I represented my directed weighted graph with `LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Double>>` to represent a vertex by its label and its values the list of vertices it's connected to with their weights.)

This is how I implemented these 2:

```
// Vertex:Distance HashMap, i.e. dist.
HashMap<String, Double> dist = new HashMap<>();

    for (String v : this.adjacencyList.keySet()) {
        dist.put(v, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
    }

dist.put(s, (double) 0);

Set<String> vertices = this.adjacencyList.keySet(); // This is Q.

while (!vertices.isEmpty()) {
!!! u ← vertex in Q with min dist[u] !!!

}
```

The `!!!` part is what I'm "stuck" on. I can think of a brute force way to do it, which is to sort `dist` and then find the smallest key that is also in `vertices`, but that does not seem like a smart way to do this. How should I go about solving this?

Since HashMaps aren't inherently sorted, I'd have to sort it in some way to get the minimum value, right? Initially it's going to be the root vertex `s` since everything else is infinity, but I should not be sorting this every iteration. Should I not use a `HashMap<String, Double>` for `dist` in the first place?

What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: what's the point of using hashmap for storing distances? you may use a usual array where `size=number of graph nodes`

Answer (score 2):

Why dont' you use TreeSet or TreeMap with custom comparator? With TreeSet you could sort all items (packed in POJO) by smallest distance. The first thing you take out from set when iterating has the smallest distance.

Here is example of such set:

```
class Elements {
    public Double distance;
    public String vertex; // Whatever you want
}

TreeSet<Elements> queue = new TreeSet<Elements>(new Comparator<Elements>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Elements a, Elements b) {
            return a.distance.compareTo(b.distance);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm new to Java and I don't really know how to construct custom comparators? How do I compare 2 strings relative to their values in ``dist``?

Comment: so what's the time complexity of adding an element into the queue? considering that Dijkstra's first part is about discovering/updating the neighbors of a node selected in second part, the first part is going to cost `O(nlogn)` if insertion takes `O(logn)` which means that the overall running time would be `O(n^2*logn)` instead of `O(n^2)`

Comment: besides, the data structure needs to deal with duplicates, because a given node could be visited more than once and hence its distance might need to be updated more than once